# commandDispatcher in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dispatcher

Quick question. Is the following code

```
var focusedWindow = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
```

only going to work in a Firefox extension? I ask because it seems to kill the script at this line and I'm wondering if command dispatcher is an internal part to Firefox?

Comment: Command dispatcher appears to be specific to XUL in mozilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command dispatcher is defined as a property on the ChromeWindow class, which is specific to Gecko applications.

Web applications should use [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement) instead, although it's not as powerful as focusedWindow.

Comment: That would be a bust my friend. Active element doesnt help what I need but thank you for clarifying just what command dispatcher was.